Warning message in wgnuplot 5.4.8 that didn't appear in version 5.4.3
I've got a script that worked well under wgnuplot 5.4.3; when running it with wgnuplot 5.4.8 it gives me a bunch of messages like "warning: Trailing characters after numeric expression". The problem comes from a user-defined function, fn(x) = gprintf("%.1f",timecolumn(1,"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") +x); when I just try a simple test of it like print fn(900) it gives me an error message that I didn't get with version 5.4.3, namely "timecolumn() called from invalid context". Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong in this new version of wgnuplot ?
Here is the script:
reset session
set term win
set datafile missing NaN
   anno1 = 2024
   mese1 = 'Gennaio' #JANUARY
   giorno1 = 1
   ora1 = '00:00'
   anno2 = 2024
   mese2 = 'Gennaio'
   giorno2 = 2
   ora2 = '00:00'
   s1 = sprintf("%02.0f",giorno1) 
   s2 = sprintf("%02.0f",giorno2)

        FILE1 = "".anno1." ".mese1." 30 min.txt"
        set locale "italian"
        set decimalsign locale "Italian"   # set input decimalsign to comma
        set decimalsign "."   # set output decimalsign to point (only with gprintf() )

   set xdata time
   set timefmt "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"
   set xrange[s1."/"."".int(tm_mon(strptime("%B",mese1))+1)."/"."".anno1.' '.ora1 : s2."/"."".int(tm_mon(strptime("%B",mese2))+1)."/"."".anno2.' '.ora2]
   set xdata

   vi = strptime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M",s1."/"."".int(tm_mon(strptime("%B",mese1))+1)."/"."".anno1.' '.ora1)
   vf = strptime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M",s2."/"."".int(tm_mon(strptime("%B",mese2))+1)."/"."".anno2.' '.ora2)

# get datafile into datablock with unix time and offset  /%m/%Y
set table $Temp1
  fn(x) = gprintf("%.1f",timecolumn(1,"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") +x)
  plot FILE1 u (fn(-900+0+0.1)):(gprintf("%.1f",$3)):(gprintf("%.1f",$5)) skip 6 w table if (fn(-900+0)>= vi && fn(-900+0)<= vf)
unset table


and the first lines of my input file called "2024 Gennaio 30 min.txt":
GENNAIO 2024                                            
                        VENTO           NOTE        
Giorno ed ora   Temperatura media   Pioggia Radiazione globale media    Tº infrarossa tetto Umidità relativa (RH)   Velocità media  Direzione media Raffica         
            [°C]  [ mm/m²] [ W/m²]   [°C]  [ % ]  [ m/s ]   gradi sessagesimali  (da nord in senso orario)  [ m/s ]         
                                            
01/01/2024 00:30    13,9    0,0 -0,5    -27,5   70  0,9 160,3   0,0 VALORI RAFFICHE ERRATI      
01/01/2024 01:00    13,9    0,0 -1,2    -27,5   72  2,5 160,4   0,0         
01/01/2024 01:30    13,4    0,0 -2,9    -27,2   76  2,0 160,4   0,0         
01/01/2024 02:00    13,0    0,4 -1,8    -27,3   77  1,3 160,4   0,0         
01/01/2024 02:30    12,9    4,2 -0,7    -21,9   78  2,8 160,7   0,2         
01/01/2024 03:00    13,1    0,0 2,3 -22,1   73  3,7 174,4   4,1         
01/01/2024 03:30    13,0    0,0 1,6 -22,5   72  2,9 179,4   0,9         
01/01/2024 04:00    13,0    0,0 1,7 -24,0   67  3,2 213,8   16,6            
01/01/2024 04:30    12,7    0,0 0,1 -24,3   66  2,5 229,8   6,8         
01/01/2024 05:00    12,3    0,0 -0,9    -24,4   68  3,1 234,9   11,3            
01/01/2024 05:30    12,3    0,0 -2,4    -24,6   67  1,3 236,1   14,6            
01/01/2024 06:00    12,1    0,0 -3,1    -25,0   67  1,8 238,9   15,2            
01/01/2024 06:30    12,1    0,0 -2,4    -25,5   67  1,6 227,5   12,2            
01/01/2024 07:00    12,0    0,0 -1,8    -26,1   67  1,8 217,4   14,6            
01/01/2024 07:30    12,1    0,0 -1,2    -26,6   66  1,2 215,4   13,2            
01/01/2024 08:00    11,7    0,0 -0,2    -26,9   68  1,4 230,0   12,8            
01/01/2024 08:30    11,4    0,0 13,0    -27,0   70  1,3 224,5   14,2            
01/01/2024 09:00    11,5    0,0 41,7    -27,1   69  0,0 192,2   0,0         
01/01/2024 09:30    11,1    0,0 78,4    -27,1   72  0,7 174,3   21,5            
01/01/2024 10:00    11,1    0,0 111,1   -27,3   71  1,4 187,3   0,4         
01/01/2024 10:30    11,3    0,0 133,6   -27,4   71  1,1 186,1   0,3         
01/01/2024 11:00    11,8    0,0 155,6   -27,5   69  0,0 186,0   0,0         
01/01/2024 11:30    12,2    0,0 206,9   -27,5   66  0,2 183,6   0,1         
01/01/2024 12:00    12,5    0,0 178,7   -27,6   65  0,3 184,9   2,1         
01/01/2024 12:30    12,9    0,0 139,1   -27,6   62  0,4 217,7   8,3         
01/01/2024 13:00    13,0    0,0 167,1   -27,6   60  0,5 232,7   10,2            
01/01/2024 13:30    13,1    0,0 141,2   -27,7   59  0,7 241,1   8,6         
01/01/2024 14:00    13,3    0,0 138,6   -27,7   59  0,3 236,9   12,4            
01/01/2024 14:30    13,1    0,0 104,5   -27,7   57  0,9 207,1   11,4            
01/01/2024 15:00    13,2    0,0 115,5   -27,6   57  0,2 225,7   6,0         
01/01/2024 15:30    13,1    0,0 80,0    -27,6   58  0,3 193,6   12,9            
01/01/2024 16:00    12,9    0,0 47,1    -27,7   59  0,5 174,2   2,7         
01/01/2024 16:30    13,0    0,0 18,4    -27,6   59  0,2 175,2   5,2         
01/01/2024 17:00    12,9    0,0 2,5 -27,9   59  0,0 0,0 0,0         
01/01/2024 17:30    12,5    0,0 -3,0    -27,7   62  0,0 171,8   0,0         
01/01/2024 18:00    12,0    0,0 -3,0    -27,6   68  0,4 170,8   0,1         
01/01/2024 18:30    11,7    0,0 -2,0    -27,6   70  0,3 170,2   1,2         
01/01/2024 19:00    11,4    0,0 -2,0    -27,5   71  0,6 169,8   0,1 VALORI RAFFICHE ERRATI      
01/01/2024 19:30    11,0    0,0 -2,7    -27,7   73  0,6 169,7   0,1         
01/01/2024 20:00    10,6    0,0 -2,8    -27,7   74  0,6 169,5   0,1         
01/01/2024 20:30    10,5    0,0 -2,7    -27,6   73  1,2 169,2   0,2         
01/01/2024 21:00    10,5    0,0 -3,7    -27,6   72  0,2 168,8   1,1         
01/01/2024 21:30    10,2    0,0 -4,1    -27,6   74  0,7 163,5   2,2         
01/01/2024 22:00    9,7 0,0 -3,3    -27,5   76  1,7 147,1   10,6            
01/01/2024 22:30    9,4 0,0 -1,6    -27,5   78  1,7 128,4   17,6            
01/01/2024 23:00    9,3 0,0 -0,8    -27,5   77  0,7 145,9   11,1            
01/01/2024 23:30    9,4 0,0 -1,7    -27,5   77  1,5 143,6   16,3            
02/01/2024 00:00    9,3 0,0 -1,2    -27,4   77  1,0 136,4   11,8            
02/01/2024 00:30    9,3 0,0 -1,7    -27,4   77  0,3 129,2   6,6         
02/01/2024 01:00    9,5 0,0 -1,9    -27,4   75  0,1 142,4   1,4         
02/01/2024 01:30    9,5 0,0 -3,2    -27,5   75  0,0 0,0 0,0         
02/01/2024 02:00    9,1 0,0 -1,5    -27,4   78  0,1 166,7   1,2         
02/01/2024 02:30    8,7 0,0 -2,1    -27,3   80  0,3 283,4   37,5            
02/01/2024 03:00    8,4 0,0 -1,5    -27,3   81  0,1 301,7   5,7         
02/01/2024 03:30    8,4 0,0 -1,7    -27,3   81  0,0 0,0 0,0         
02/01/2024 04:00    8,5 0,0 -2,0    -27,3   81  0,6 143,6   14,5


The command print fn(900) indeed calls timecolumn() from an invalid context, since there is no "column 1" from which to read a time string if the program is not in the process of reading a data file.
As to the warning message about trailing characters, that is only a warning, not an error.  The content of table $Temp1 should still be correct.
I suspect that the warning message is generated because the program is confused about what the proper decimal sign is because both conditions are satisfied (1) the program is inside the using specifier of an input operation - so the input locale would be appropriate and (2) the program is inside a call to gprintf - so the output decimal point would be appropriate.  Maybe it tries both and one works while the other generates this message?  I am not entirely sure of the internal algorithm to resolve this, but in any case when tested on my linux machine it looks to me that the output is correct. You should check the content of $Temp1 yourself to be sure your machine also does the right thing.
Update
After some investigation I have found that the warning message comes from the if condition in your plot command, not from the actual processing of the input data.  The test is
if (fn(-900+0)>= vi && fn(-900+0)<= vf)

vi and vf are numerical values representing time in seconds.  But fn(...) returns a string, not a number.  The warning message comes when gnuplot tries to auto-convert that string to a number and runs into conflicting locales.  The string was created with gprintf() to use period as decimal point, but since the if is part of an input evaluation the program is expected a comma as the decimal point.
I am pretty sure what you really want is this:
fd(x) = timecolumn(1,"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") + x
plot FILE1 u (fn(-900+0+0.1)):(gprintf("%.1f",$3)):(gprintf("%.1f",$5)) skip 6 w table if (fd(-900+0)>= vi && fd(-900+0)<= vf)

You might want fd() instead of fn() for the first column of output also, but that's not the one that is generating the warning messages.

Indeed $Temp1 comes out well, with the decimal point being a dot and not a comma. The warning message comes twice for each data line, since for each row of the datafile there are two calls to the function as shown in if (fn(-900+0)>= vi && fn(-900+0)<= vf) which is quite bothersome when your datafile is a bit large as it is mine. The funniest thing is that under version 5.4.3 it didn't protest...

The decimal point of the datafile is "," ; when changing it to "." and set decimalsign locale "Italian" to "English" (or just set locale "English"), it doesn't show any warning (at this point, set decimalsign "." can be removed). So it looks like the user-defined function fn(x) = gprintf("%.1f",timecolumn(1,"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") +x) of the current wgnuplot version cannot handle decimalsigns other than "." ;would there be a workaround before someone fixes this (apparent) bug ?

What bug?  I thought you confirmed that the output, as stored in $temp1, is correct.  I agree that the warning is annoying, but in that case I would think the work-around is to ignore the warning.  Do you get different output from the earlier gnuplot version, or is the only difference the presence or absence of a warning?

Note that in the current gnuplot version (6.0) you can suppress the warning messages by saying "unset warning".

The only difference is the presence of the warning. The output is ok, problem is that I have another datafile much bigger and there, it takes minutes to stop from displaying warnings (the same message, thousands of times, twice for every data line). Another workaround would be to change the decimalsign every time (a bit annoying), or re-install version 5.4.3; version 6.0 does not exist for windows (yet). The latest is 5.4.8

Windows binaries for the version 6 release were a bit delayed, but they should be available now from the gnuplot project site on SourceForge.

That's true, it's already available. I'll check that out. Meanwhile, should I find the solution of the mystery, I'll let you know

@ Ethan I hadn't seen the update, prior to my latest comments... sorry for that. Indeed it's as you said. I've checked by my part and encountered the same as you. I was about to post it and saw your update. gprintf returns a string, not a number, so it cannot be compared with any number. Only its (numeric) argument can. Still I first added a 0.+ before the fn(-900+0) in if (fn(-900+0)>= vi && fn(-900+0)<= vf) since generally that transforms the following string (if numerical) to a number. But it didn't. Anyway that doesn't matter already since the warning is already out.

It's funny however that wgnuplot version 5.4.3 didn't realize of that error and run the script well and without warnings, like "knowing what I indeed wanted". Maybe that version was more intelligent...
